# Set virtual host for ubuntu on NTFS partition

Tags: apache2, ntfs, virtualhost

I have just installed ubuntu on my laptop and getting used to it. I have a local wamp server running on a windows partition on the same laptop. I want to use the same root directory for my ubuntu apache root or maybe create a virtual host.

I have tried numerous options giving permissions to the folders, trying to share the folders, setting up another virtual host with a different name, but every time I get 403 forbidden error. I have heard it might be due to work group permissions, but as I am new to linux, unaware of the fact how it works and how to implement it. Please help.

Screen shot of error

[image: Screen shot of error]

Comment: 403 forbidden error to what file index.html ??

Comment: @Neil yes or any other file

Comment: run this command  "ls -n /var/www/html/" and put the output in your post

Comment: @Neil 
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 11510 Oct 23 22:54 index.html

Comment: but i want to set localhost as ntfs partition root.
its path is /media/sanket/STUFF/wamp/www/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it worked after changed the following in envvars file 
/etc/apache2/envvars

export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data

export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

to

export APACHE_RUN_USER=sanket

export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=sanket

Well for subdirectories inside your virtual host adding the following directory permissions worked for me

```
<Directory /virtualhost/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Don't forget to chmod -R 755 on your virtual host directory

Answer (score 1):

Easy way of changing the root of Apache is create a symbolic link.
You will need to go to /var/www/ and delete html

```
sudo rm /var/www/html -Rf
```

**this command will delete every thing in /var/www/html**

Then create a html fodder in /media/sanket/STUFF/wamp

```
sudo mkdir /media/sanket/STUFF/wamp/www/html
```

put your index.html and other stuff in the html fodder.

Now create the symbolic link.

```
sudo ln -s /media/sanket/STUFF/wamp/www/html /var/www/html
```

Now make sure the right permissions are set

```
sudo chmod ugo+wr /media/sanket/STUFF/wamp/www/html -Rf
```

Hope it answers your question.

**edit**

Open up a terminal and type in

```
sudo chmod ugo+wrx /var/www -Rf
```

and then type in

```
sudo chmod ugo+wrx /var/www/html/ -Rf
```

Comment: It still gives me 403 forbidden error

Comment: can you take a screen shot of the error page ?

Comment: posted in question

Comment: not sure if workgroup permissions matter. any idea how do we give it?

Comment: edited my post.

Comment: actually it worked after changed the following in envvars file
/etc/apache2/envvars
export APACHE_RUN_USER=sanket
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=sanket

Comment: if that solved the problem and I had nothing to do with it. click on the Answer Your Question button.